# displaying dataframes in Julia/Juno

Tags: dataframe, julia, display

I am trying to display a dataframe using showtable() from TableView. I am using Julia 1.4.1 in Atom 1.46.0 (Juno). 
The table displays in the plot window but only the column names display, and the table itself is empty of any entries. Example below :

```
a = randn(100)
b = randn(100) .+ 3
data = DataFrame(a=a, b=b)
showtable(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following code today with TableView version 0.6.0

```
using DataFrames, TableView, Blink

a = randn(100)
b = randn(100) .+ 3
data = DataFrame(a=a, b=b)

w = Window() # Open a new window
body!(w, showtable(data))
```

[image]